# R/ggplot2: geom_contour_filled doesn't give me the whole plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to draw a contour plot of the Trebuchet data from `library(fastR2)`. However, my first attempt is giving me a very strange result:

```
ggplot(data = Trebuchet) +
  geom_contour_filled(aes(projectileWt,counterWt,z=distance),bins=10)
```

[image]

As you can see, there is a lot of gray space, that really shouldn't be there: the Trebuchet data has plenty of data for projectile weights and counterweights that would fall into the grey area. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: Plot `ggplot(data = Trebuchet, aes(projectileWt,counterWt,z=distance)) + geom_jitter(height = 0.02) + geom_contour_filled(alpha = 0.5)` to see that the data is not evenly spread out. From the help for `geom_contour`: "Contouring tends to work best when x and y form a (roughly) evenly spaced grid. If your data is not evenly spaced, you may want to interpolate to a grid before visualising, see geom_density_2d()."

Comment: Thanks, I see what you mean! I'll look into geom_desity_2d.